# AJAX request, redirect with params

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
               url: baseUrl,
               type: "post",
               contentType: "application/json",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {
                window.location = ('http://localhost:9000/#/home.html?' +  (data.search))
               },
               data: JSON.stringify(body),
             });
             return false;
           }
         };
```

this is my ajax request, it sends as JSON and it returns an object

ie. search = {firstName: km, lastname: b}

However, ajax isnt setting the content type to JSON for the params in the redirect. It is still sending as an object. JSON stringify does not work. Is there a way to set the content type to JSON inside the success/redirect function?

JSON.stringify just decodes the object into

```
%7B%22clientName%22:%blah%22,%22em%22:%22mLigDACsBihAL2RETse06351MuCNehZQ%22,%22partnercode%22:%blah%22%7D
```

Comment: So data.search contains a JSON string? I am not quite clear on what your question is asking. Try printing out what data.search contains.

Comment: what is the value of body ?

Comment: I gave an example, search is formatted like this:
search:
{clientName: "google", em: "mLigDACsBihAL2RETse06351MuCNehZQ", partnercode: "google"}

Comment: if you want to redirect to a url sending it json data you're probably better off with another `ajax` inside the success function, the inner ajax's success will replace `<body>` with the result from the server if that's what you intend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/):

```
var qs = $.param(data.search);
window.location = 'http://localhost:9000/#/home.html?' + qs;
```

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because it trying to send an object to your window.location part.
 What you probably need is this:

```
 window.location = ('http://localhost:9000/#/home.html?firstName=' +  data.search.firstName + "&lastname=" + data.search.lastname)
```

Comment: the return data will not always be the same so I cannot set each param like that